# Can I single cycle through an HTML program. I want to find out where each message comes from

Tags: html

I am working through HackThis Basic problems to learn how HTML works. In Basic Level 2 I get a message "User agent not accepted, only secure_user_agent allowed". Inspecting the code shows the message but not why it was generated. User Agent is a Browser attribute. I am using Firefox and Linux Mint 18.3.
I am learning HTML from sites which supply problems for programmers to solve.

I've tried to 'Inspect Element' which shows me the message in the code. However, I can't find out why this message is shown.

```
https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/basic+/2

<div class="msg msg-error">
   <i class="icon-error">
      ::before
</i>
  User agent not accepted, only secure_user_agent allowed
 </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like your using HTTP and not HTTP**S**

Answer (score 0):

open the Developer Tools ( Ctrl + shift + i ) click the device icon at the left top of the Developer Tools window ( beside the search icon ) a device mode will appear in the top of your web page in front of UA (User Agent) replace the "no override" with "secure_user_agent"

Comment: I have tried this but can't find the 'device icon'. Here is a screenshot: